# ansible condition validation not skip the rest condition when first failed

Tags: python, jinja2, ansible

If `vlan` variable is not defined in ansible, however, ansible will still fail in the following case. In other language, if the first condition failed, the rest condition should be ignored (short circuiting). How to workaround this in Ansible?

```
- name: Validate vlan ID
  when: vlan is defined and ({{ vlan }} < 1 or {{ vlan }} > 4094)
  fail: msg='VLAN {{vlan}} is not in the range of [1, 4094]'
```

---

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/runtime.py", line 485, in _fail_with_undefined_error
raise self._undefined_exception(hint)
UndefinedError: 'vlan' is undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're experiencing comes from trying to access the contents of vlan with `{{ }}`. If you update your task to the below syntax, the task will be skipped.

```
- name: Validate vlan ID
  when: vlan is defined and (vlan < 1 or vlan > 4094)
  fail: msg='VLAN {{vlan}} is not in the range of [1, 4094]'
```

Comment: With your suggestion, I got the following  issue:
msg: VLAN 2333 is not in the range of [1, 4094]

Comment: This is when vlan is not defined? I ran a sample and the task was skipped when vlan was undefined

Comment: This happens when I define vlan to value 2333. maybe related to string or number?

Comment: Can you share the yml where you set vlan? The only way I was able to reproduce your error was by setting vlan to be the string '2333' instead of setting to the number 2333. In that case, you would need to either set vlan as a number or parse vlan in the when evaluation.

Comment: I run via playbook with -e vlan=2333. As you can see from above message the vlan id is not a string

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly I have to use the following format with "-e vlan=2333" to pass the following condition:
when: vlan is defined and (vlan|int < 1 or vlan|int > 4094)

Thanks Andrew for great hint!